# Eclipse for Linux gets stuck in splash screen

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I know this problem has been asked hundreds of time but what I am having is a little bit different and no method is applicable for my eclipse installation.

When I try to start eclipse in ubuntu it starts up and shows the splash screen but then changes to white splash screen. While most answer on this relies on the fact that the .snap file should be deleted from some particular folder in workspace, my problem is eclipse has never started fully and don't have any workspace folder yet. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is it? From where? Installed how? On what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Its ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Eclipse Luna 4.4.2. Its the latest version of eclipse downloaded from eclipse.org. I even tried eclipse Kepler and got the same problem. Tried it with both Orale Java 1.7 and 1.8